node_exporter is running on linux but while connecting from browser connection is not getting established
I have install node_export on linux machine and after all the configuration and setup node_exporter is running on linux. But when I’m try to connect with virtualmachineIP:9100 browser is not connecting. Prometheus is installed on same server and it is getting connected. I have also tried with running command ./node_exporter still i was not able to connect.
I want to connect node_exporter from the browser

I have tried same process on AWS ec2 instance and it is working fine there but on AZURE VM, node exporter is not connecting.
